# Включение/отключение Deeplinks

Tags: java, android, kotlin, flutter, android-manifest

Есть ли возможность в Android программно (во время выполнения приложения) включать и отлючать реагирование его на [Deeplinks](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/epam_systems/blog/461239/

Comment: @MiT, спасибо, приложение и вправду пишется на Flutter и потому оно было добавлено в теги. Но вопрос состоит немного в другом, как отключать/включать тот факт что приложение может принимать ссылки такого типа? Пусть даже через перезауск приложения, что вполне логично.

Comment: придется делать через натив и [PlatformChanal](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels), я не вижу возможности как это сделать через Flutter...

Comment: @MiT, отлично! Я встречал данное решение для нейтив, но найти не могу. Если у вас есть решение, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: Насколько я знаю Deeplinks в Android включаются через `AndroidManifest.xml` (и его редактировать когда приложение работает нельзя), а также вызовом метода `intent.getData();`. Возможно можно поместить данный участок кода в `if()` и сделать проверку, на основе данной проверки разрешать или запрещать работу Deeplinks. В iOS я думаю по аналогии будет... _Костыль и велосипедостроение))_

Comment: Да думал я об этом, но этот костыль более не приятный чем просто возможность выбора приложения, так как этот костыль будет в любом случае предлагать сделать выбор приложения (если не выбрано приложение по умолчанию), далее будет открыто активити и там выполнена проверка, и при отключённости данной функции это активити закроется. Так себе поведение...

Comment: сложный, кейс... На данный момент я ни чем не смогу вам помочь. Надеюсь у вас все получиться!